# How to specify location targeting of FB post via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, targeting

Some time ago there was a field called `targeting` in the [Post API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) but now it's gone and I don't know how to add a specific location and language targeting to the post via API. I've search a lot: some results refer to the `targeting` parameter. I've tried it, but it seems don't working.

I've tried 2 ways to achieve this, but without any success:

```
$post_details = array('message' => $msg, 'privary' => array('value' => 'CUSTOM', 'description' => array('country' => 'Germany')));
$fb->api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST', $post_details);
```

and

```
$post_details = array('message' => $msg, 'targeting' => array('country' => 'Germany'));
$fb->api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST', $post_details);
```

Please help me understand how can I achieve this?

Comment: can anyone give me a direction? it's urgent, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for targeting, see the `privacy` property of the post object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

> The description field may contain a comma-separated lists of valid
>   country, city and language if a Page's post targeting by
>   location/language is specified.
>
> Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or
>   specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted
>   Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page,
>   event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on
>   Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the
>   target's Wall.

Comment: Can you help me understand what "if a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified" means? Is there another setting that has to be set to specify targeting?

Answer (score 2):

instead of `privacy` you also can use `feed_targeting`

All parameters which you can target like languages,cities,counties are facebook specific. You can resolve them via autocomplete data :

"{'locales':[1001],'countries':[GE],'cities':[825886]}"

Nice feature for automatic posting with targeting but so bad documented in the Facebook documentation...

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier this is the bit you need http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#targeting

this will give the info on how to target cities too. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

a more complete solution from me on this question  [Geotargeting Page Posts with the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893981/geotargeting-page-posts-with-the-facebook-api/)