# providing targeting filtering in page posts queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to pass a targeting query to the graph api when requesting facebook posts?
If so, how should this be done ?

I found this question:

[How to specify location targeting of FB post via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629610/how-to-specify-location-targeting-of-fb-post-via-graph-api)

And this one

[Geotargeting Page Posts with the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893981/geotargeting-page-posts-with-the-facebook-api/)

But it doesn't seem to work, I've been trying the following in the graph explorer.
And a lot more permutations as well.

```
PAGE_ID/posts?fields=targeting({'countries' : ['DE'] })
PAGE_ID/posts?fields=targeting("{'countries' : ['DE'] }")
PAGE_ID/posts?targeting={'countries' : ['DE'] }
PAGE_ID/posts?targeting={countries : ['DE'] }
PAGE_ID/posts?targeting="{'countries' : ['DE'] }"
PAGE_ID/posts?targeting="{countries : ['DE'] }"
```

With all these queries I keep just getting non filtered results or errors.

Is there a correct way to do it, and is there maybe any documentation anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use query qualifications like you posted witht he Graph API in general. The `targeting` and `feed_targeting` fields are set upon the publishing of Posts (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#pubfields).

What you could try is using the FQL stream table to get the posts with a certain targeting:

```
select post_id from stream where source_id={page_id} and feed_targeting.country in ('DE')
```

Be sure to notice the access restrictions:

> To read the stream table you need read_stream permissions for all
>   posts that the current session user is able to view, read_insights
>   permissions to see post impressions for any posts made by a Page owned
>   by the current session user.